# Is there a programmatic way to check if an Entity Framework class meets the requirements for Proxy generation

Tags: .net, entity-framework, entity-framework-5

I realise it is possible to put together a function that will check all the requirements listed on http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/dd468057(v=vs.100).aspx but I am hoping that there is an easier way?

Answer (score 1):

A simple way is to use a test class.  That checks the proxy is there. Otherwise I think you will find it is code and reflection. Perhaps someone has already written the check.

**edit: here is the MS sample is it a proxy check**

[How to identify Poco proxy](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/ee835846%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)